# Transition after Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm programming an application with an initial logo activity.
It has to be displayed for 1 second and then launch the main activity using a custom transition.

The problem is that the logo activity is displayed for 1 second, but the animation is quite always the standard and rarely displays the custom animation I made.

This is the code in logoActivity.class :

```
        Thread thread;
        i = new Intent(this, mainActivity.class);
        thread=  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){
                    Log.d("Event Loop", "Exception: " + ex.toString());
                }
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_out, R.anim.anim_in);
                finish();
            }
        };
```

this is the code in anim_out.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
android:fromXDelta="0%p"
android:toXDelta="100%p"></translate>
```

and this is the code in anim_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
android:toXDelta="0%p"></translate>
```

I use those animations to set the custom transition from mainActivity and secondActivity too, and it works perfectly.

Please, help me solving this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a countDownTimer which is better than this approach.

```
   CountDownTimer   timer = new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
                 startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_out, R.anim.anim_in);
                finish();

            }
        };
        timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your intention is to display a kind of SplashScreen between activities with a custom animation instead of a single image.

Here`s an excellent tutorial on how to do this

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App